# (Middling) good morphisms of triangles

Tags: derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Neeman in his article ["Some new axioms for triangulated categories"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939190292G) calls a morphism of distinguished triangles

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> Y @>>> Z @>>> X [1] \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
X' @>>> Y' @>>> Z' @>>> X' [1]
\end{CD}$$

**middling good** if it may be completed to a $3\times 3$ diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> Y @>>> Z @>>> X [1] \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
X' @>>> Y' @>>> Z' @>>> X' [1] \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
X'' @>>> Y'' @>>> Z'' @>>> X'' [1] \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
X [1] @>>> Y [1] @>>> Z [1] @>>> X [2]
\end{CD}$$

where all columns and all rows are distinguished, and all squares commute, except for the bottom right square, which anti-commutes.

Not every morphism of distinguished triangles is middling good; what is true is that given a diagram

$$\tag{*} \require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>u>> Y @>v>> Z @>w>> X [1] \\
@VVV @VVV \\
X' @>>> Y' @>>> Z' @>>> X' [1]
\end{CD}$$

there exists some arrow $Z \to Z'$ making it a middling good morphism of triangles (this is one way to phrase the "triangulated nine-lemma"; see e.g. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05R0).

Neeman also introduces the notion of a **good** morphism of triangles and shows that "good" implies "middling good" (see the article mentioned above or the first chapter of his book).

---

I haven't seen much practical applications of that, so here are some naive questions.

1. A rather vague question: how does one check in practice that a particular morphism is middling good? E.g. one **very** special case is when the morphism $Z\to Z'$ in (*) is unique; this happens for instance when $\operatorname{Hom} (X [1], Z') = 0$, as one sees from the exact sequence
   $$\operatorname{Hom} (X [1], Z') \xrightarrow{w^*} \operatorname{Hom} (Z, Z') \xrightarrow{v^*} \operatorname{Hom} (Y, Z').$$
2. Do things become easier if we work, say, with the derived category of vector spaces? What is a middling good morphism of triangles in that case?
3. One might be interested in the following weaker condition: in a derived category, suppose we are interested in completing a morphism of distinguished triangles to a $3\times 3$ diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> Y @>>> Z @>>> X [1] \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
X' @>>> Y' @>>> Z' @>>> X' [1] \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
X'' @>>> Y'' @>>> Z'' @>>> X'' [1] \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
X [1] @>>> Y [1] @>>> Z [1] @>>> X [2]
\end{CD}$$

where the columns are distinguished and the third row is not necessarily distinguished, but at least induces a long exact sequence in cohomology
$$\cdots \to H^i (X'') \to H^i (Y'') \to H^i (Z'') \to H^{i+1} (X'') \to \cdots$$
Is it always possible to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: For 2: yes, things become much easier in semi-simple triangulated categories. Moreover, is suspect that for an abelian category $A$ of cohomological dimension $\le 1$ (in the vector space case the cohomological dimension is zero) any morphism of distinguished triangles is good.

Comment: @Mikhail Bondarko I am mostly interested in the derived category of abelian groups, i.e. cohomological dimension 1. Do you have a reference for your claim? I was also suspecting that, but couldn't figure it out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry; I don't know any references for this matter. Sometimes it helps to replace objects by coproducts of two-term complexes of projectives.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko In the derived category D(Z) of abelian groups, it is not true that every morphism of triangles is good.  In fact, not every morphism is middling good.  I can't type math in a comment and this doesn't qualify as an answer to the original question, so I'm hesitant to post the details as an answer.  But I will post a link to a preprint that gives an example when it is ready.