# Can morphisms of Mayer-Vietoris triangles be completed into a $3\times 3$ square?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-cohomology, triangulated-categories, cech-cohomology

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a topological ringed space and $(U,V)$ be an open covering of $X$ (i.e. $U$ and $V$ are two open subsets of $X$ such that $U\cup V=X$). Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}'$ be sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

By the Mayer-Vietoris triangle (see [73.10.5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CRS)), one has a distinguished triangle in the derived category of $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$-modules:
$$R\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})\to R\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})\oplus R\Gamma(V,\mathcal{F})\stackrel{(1,-1)}{\longrightarrow}R\Gamma(U\cap V,\mathcal{F})\to [1].$$
Let $f:\mathcal{F}\to \mathcal{F}'$ be a morphism of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. It induces maps of complexes in the derived category: $f_X:R\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})\to R\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}')$, $f_U:R\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})\to R\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F}')$, $f_V:R\Gamma(V,\mathcal{F})\to R\Gamma(V,\mathcal{F}')$ and $f_{U\cap V}:R\Gamma(U\cap V,\mathcal{F})\to R\Gamma(U\cap V,\mathcal{F}')$. It allows us to complete the diagram into a morphism of distinguished triangles:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
R\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}) @>>> R\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})\oplus R\Gamma(V,\mathcal{F}) @>>> R\Gamma(U\cap V,\mathcal{F}) @>>> [1] \\
@VVf_XV @VVf_U\oplus f_{V}V @VVf_{U\cap V}V @VVV \\
R\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}') @>>> R\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F}')\oplus R\Gamma(V,\mathcal{F}') @>>> R\Gamma(U\cap V,\mathcal{F}') @>>> [1]
\end{CD}$$
Not every morphism of triangles can be completed into a $3\times 3$ square (see this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286086/middling-good-morphisms-of-triangles), or [Neeman's paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939190292G)). Here is my question:

> Is the morphism of triangle $(f_X, f_{U}\oplus f_{V}, f_{U\cap V})$ **middling good** in the sense of Neeman? In other terms, can the above diagram be completed into
> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> R\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}) @>>> R\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})\oplus R\Gamma(V,\mathcal{F}) @>>> R\Gamma(U\cap V,\mathcal{F}) @>>> [1] \\
> @VVf_XV @VVf_U\oplus f_{V}V @VVf_{U\cap V}V @VVV \\
> R\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}') @>>> R\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F}')\oplus R\Gamma(V,\mathcal{F}') @>>> R\Gamma(U\cap V,\mathcal{F}') @>>> [1] \\
> @VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
> \operatorname{cone}(f_X) @>>> \operatorname{cone}(f_{U}\oplus f_{V}) @>>> \operatorname{cone}(f_{U\cap V}) @>>> [1] \\
> @VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
> [1] @>>> [1] @>>> [1] @>>> [1]
> \end{CD}$$
> where all columns and all rows are distinguished, and all squares commute, except for the bottom right square, which anti-commutes?

In particular, we would be able to deduce a Mayer-Vietoris triangle not only for sheaves, but also morphisms of sheaves:

> $$R\Gamma\left(X,\mathcal{F}\stackrel{f}{\to}\mathcal{F}'\right)\to R\Gamma\left(U,\mathcal{F}\stackrel{f}{\to}\mathcal{F}'\right)\oplus R\Gamma\left(V,\mathcal{F}\stackrel{f}{\to}\mathcal{F}'\right)\longrightarrow R\Gamma\left(U\cap V,\mathcal{F}\stackrel{f}{\to}\mathcal{F}'\right)\to [1]$$
> where the notation $R\Gamma\left(X,\mathcal{F}\stackrel{f}{\to}\mathcal{F}'\right)$ stems for $\operatorname{Tot}(f_X)=\operatorname{cone}[-1](f_X)$.

Aside from an answer, any comment, reference, example or discussion would be surely very inspiring to me. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it can. It seems that your last couple questions have to do with the pathologies that arise in triangulated categories due to non-functorial cones.  These pathologies almost never matter in practice, because the triangulated categories that mathematicians  actually use are in fact the homotopy categories of dg-enhanced/stable infinity categories-- these have functorial cones "built in."   From a lowbrow perspective, you can just construct your diagram as a strictly commuting diagram of honest chain complexes and take the cones of this diagram to obtain the desired square.

Comment: @PhilTosteson Thank you very much. I agree with your comment. However, the question is rather then: how does one show that $f_X$ indeed comes from the functorial cone construction? (maybe I am missing something...)