# 3x3 lemma in triangulated categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

I am currently reading Le Stum's *Rigid Cohomology* and have encountered the following passage (proof of Proposition 5.2.16):
[image: Diagram]
The deduction made here seems to be purely "triangulated category-theoretical", using a statement of the following sort:

> ("Triangulated 3x3 lemma") Given a diagram as above, if all columns and two of the rows form exact triangles, we have that the third row is also exact.

This statement, if true, would be a direct analogue of the [3x3 lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_lemma) in abelian categories. Unfortunately I am not familiar with a version of this result in derived or triangulated categories. However it is not clear to me that it is possible to deduce the result here, even in the setting of derived categories (which we are in in the passage above) (it's not clear since I see no reason why the entire diagram would arise from a 3x3 array with exact sequences).

The only related result I found is the one considered in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24257/127263), however I again don't see how could be applicable, since the 3x3 array formed there needn't coincide with the one I have here*.

Therefore here is my question: is there a version of the nine lemma in triangulated categories like I have outlined above? Maybe at least in the case of derived categories? If there is no such general result, can we justify the passage above in the special case?

*A colleague of mine mentions that such nonuniqueness issues are avoided if we work in a different setting, like that of "pretriangulated DG categories", but that theory is unfamiliar to me, so I don't know if a related result holds there and, if so, whether it would be transferable to the case at hand. While I would value any insight, I am mostly looking for an answer in the triangulated/derived category setting.

Comment: There is a standard $3x3$ lemma in triangulated categories.   See for example Lemma 2.6 in \url{http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/AddJan01.pdf}.

Comment: @PeterMay Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I'm not sure how this result resolves my question, for similar reasons as for why the question I link doesn't - the nonuniqueness if morphisms between triangles doesn't seem to guarantee I get the right diagram when applying the lemma.

Comment: I don't think it matters: there is an object in the top right hand corner making everything commute and every triangle exact, as in the lemma in Peter's link, and that object must also make the right vertical sequence an exact triangle thus it must be (up to non unique isomorphism, but isomorphism nonetheless) the same as the one that was initially in your diagram.Then you can identify the missing map with the map that's already in your diagram, again, up to (nonunique) isomorphism, and this gives you that your triangle is exact up to isomorphism, which means it's exact

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think that makes sense. If you could spell out this argument in an answer I could accept it.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think you misread the lemma ; your argument breaks down at "that object must also make the right vertical sequence an exact triangle". The lemma says that there _exists_ an arrow $\mathcal{E}\to h_\ast h^{-1}\mathcal{E}$ and an object in the top right corner making everything right. The problem is that we have no control over this new arrow.

Comment: See also [Middling good morphism of triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286086/middling-good-morphisms-of-triangles) and for a specific counterexample in D(Z), example 8.5 in Christensen, Frankland, [On good morphisms of exact triangle](https://jdc.math.uwo.ca/papers/good-morphisms.pdf)

Comment: I am not familiar with this book so I may have misinterpreted some notations but, as far as I can tell, the second raw in your diagram ($\mathcal E\to\mathcal E\oplus\mathcal E\to\mathcal E\to$) is split-exact, not just a triangle. If this is the case, the map $\mathcal E\oplus\mathcal E\to\mathcal E$ is actually a cokernel and so, by the universal property of cokers, you have a unique choice for the morphism $\mathcal E\to h_*h_1^{-1}\mathcal E$ that makes the diagram commute.

Comment: Since there is always a way to complete a commutative square to a middling good morphism of triangles, we deduce from the above uniqueness argument that the canonical morphism of triangles, say $\Phi=[\phi_{1,2},\phi_{1\oplus 2},\phi]$, from $\mathcal E\to\mathcal E\oplus\mathcal E\to\mathcal E\to$ to $h_{1,2*}h_{1,2}^{-1}\mathcal E\to h_{1*}h_{1}^{-1}\mathcal E\oplus h_{2*}h_{2}^{-1}\mathcal E\to h_{*}h^{-1}\mathcal E\to$ is middling good. Hence, there is a triangle $C(\phi_{1,2})\to C(\phi_{1\oplus 2})\to C(\phi)\to$ which, up to a shift, is what you need for the proof of Prop.5.2.16